SQL Server query based on column for returned rows
How do I write a SQL Server query based on a column in table for how many rows I want returned?
Say the table has 2 rows with 3 columns. The 3rd column is how many rows I want to return and this 3rd column has a value of 3,2 (different for each row).
I want a result of 5 rows, that would display the same value in column 1 & 2 3 times and column 1 & 2 2 times. With a total result of 5 rows returned.
I show the data in the table below
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] (InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded) 
VALUES ('A1000', 'Company 1', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[Table1] (InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded) 
VALUES ('A1001', 'Company 2', 2)

Returned result set:
'A1000','Company 1'
'A1000','Company 1'
'A1000','Company 1'
'A1001','Company 2'
'A1001','Company 2'


You can use generate_series(..) to return multiple rows. What DBMS is used?

you can use recursive cte & and you don't need hierarchy joins with itself:
with cte as (
  select InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded, 1 as rn
  from Table1
  union all
  select InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded, rn + 1 as rn 
  from cte 
  where rn < RowsNeeded
)

select InvoiceID, CompanyName 
from cte
order by InvoiceID, CompanyName

output :



InvoiceID
CompanyName




A1000
Company 1


A1000
Company 1


A1000
Company 1


A1001
Company 2


A1001
Company 2



fiddle

You could use a recursive hierarchical CTE:
WITH cte (InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded, level) AS  (
    SELECT InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded, 1 AS level
    FROM Table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.InvoiceID, t2.CompanyName, t2.RowsNeeded, t2.level + 1
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN cte t2
        ON t2.InvoiceID = t1.InvoiceID AND
           t1.level + 1 <= t1.RowsNeeded
)

SELECT InvoiceID, CompanyName
FROM cte
ORDER BY InvoiceID;

The strategy here is to simply replicate each invoice record RowsNeeded number of times.


First, a recursive CTE named RecursiveCTE is created. It starts with selecting InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded from Table1, where RowNumber is set to 1.

Then, a join operation (JOIN) occurs between RecursiveCTE and Table1 based on the condition r.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID, selecting data from table t, and incrementing RowNumber by 1. This step repeats until RowNumber is less than RowsNeeded.

Eventually, a SELECT query is executed to choose InvoiceID and CompanyName from RecursiveCTE, sorted by InvoiceID.

The OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) option specifies the maximum recursion depth (in this case, unlimited).
 WITH RecursiveCTE AS (
   SELECT InvoiceID, CompanyName, RowsNeeded, 1 AS RowNumber
   FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT t.InvoiceID, t.CompanyName, t.RowsNeeded, RowNumber + 1
   FROM RecursiveCTE r
   JOIN Table1 t ON r.InvoiceID = t.InvoiceID
   WHERE RowNumber < t.RowsNeeded
 )

 SELECT InvoiceID, CompanyName
 FROM RecursiveCTE
 ORDER BY InvoiceID
 OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);




Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

See example with generate_series(...)
select t.*,sn.value as n
from Table1 t
cross apply generate_series(1,coalesce(nullif(t.RowsNeeded,0),1))sn




InvoiceID
CompanyName
RowsNeeded




A1000
Company 1
3


A1001
Company 2
2


A1002
Company 3
1


A1003
Company 4
0






InvoiceID
CompanyName
RowsNeeded
n




A1000
Company 1
3
1


A1000
Company 1
3
2


A1000
Company 1
3
3


A1001
Company 2
2
1


A1001
Company 2
2
2


A1002
Company 3
1
1


A1003
Company 4
0
1



Simpler example, where RowsNeeded is not less than 1
select t.*,sn.value as n
from Table1 t
cross apply generate_series(1,t.RowsNeeded)sn

fiddle
